# Detect black rectangles on white sheet from webcam video using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, keyboard, tracking, detection

I am working on a project on virtual keyboard.
Using the webcam, I want to detect black keys on a projected keyboard on a wall (projected using a projector).

The keyboard has white background with black keys - [image: Image of keyboard]

As it is projected, there will be some continuous movement of the keyboard, although little.
From my understanding, I will have to detect this white rectangle, then further detect the black keys in it for every frame.

Can you please tell if this is correct?
How do I go about it using Python and OpenCV?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you whant to create a functioning projected keyboard. If it is the case, you effectively whant to first map the position of the projected keys in the webcam image. Then detect a "press" position in this same image.   By comparing the two information you will be allowed to "detect" a "keypress". first at all, since detecting the "press" position is the harder, what do you imagine to do that ? (I will then tell you what can be done to map the keys positions)(this is a seriously advanced project dude)

Comment: Yes,I want to do exactly that. But the first difficulty is taking the keyboard as input from webcam, detecting the black keys (rectangles) separately and storing their coordinates (say centroid in a file). I've used this approach in MATLAB. How do i take frame by frame input from webcam video and apply detection of rectangles to it?

Comment: And I will try to detect the 'keypress' using a red colored band on finger. By probably subtracting subsequent frames and filtering only for red color. Creating a box around that and taking its centroid. So both centroids can be henceforth compared

Comment: for this task you can use the class Blobdetector http://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/  but i find it better to map the "projected image coordinate vs source image coordinate fonction" by projection of a well known patern, then do a "colission detection" bettwin the projectedToSourcePOS(pressed pos) and the "sources keys colisions boxs"

Comment: So you're saying to use a pre-stored image? That would be the better thing to do, but I want to make this project moveable. What I mean is - the size and projection position of keyboard will be different every time we use it. It will dynamic. So I cannot pre-store the coordinates. It must map the keys freshly in each use and then proceed with key press detection

Comment: the calibrqtion can be very quick if well codded, but this is true that you must calibrated at every mouve. the goal of this methode is to improve precision.